# PHP+MongoDB dynamic queries - adding conditional operators

Tags: php, mongodb, dynamicquery

I am making use of dynamic queries in mongoDB, by using them this way:

```
$query['clicks'] = array('$gt' => 6);
$query['lang'] = "de";

$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

The question is pretty simple and straightforward: how can one add 'OR' conditionals? for example to have both 'lang' to be "de" OR "fr";

Because right now, Mongo implies that there is an AND between "clicks" and "lang". So how can i structure clicks > 6 && ( lang == 'de' || lang == 'fr' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give try as below

```
$query['clicks'] = array('$gt' => 6);
$query['$or'] = array(array('lang' => 'de'), array('lang' => 'fr'));
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

How to add $in operator

```
$query['clicks'] = array('$gt' => 6);
$query['$or'] = array(array('lang' => 'de'), array('lang' => 'fr'));
$query['_id'] = array('$in' => array(new mongoId('506d95bc5c73952c14000002'), new mongoId('506d95bc5c73952c14000003')));

$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

Comment: thank you. you get the right answer for simplicity. Just a quick one tho:  `$query['$or'] = array(array('lang' => 'fr'), array('lang' => 'de'));
 $query['$or'] = array(array('_id' => new mongoId('506d95bc5c73952c14000002')));` how can I "add" the second 'or' to the first? the way it is now, it just overwrites it. I know it's out of the scope of the question but, well..

Comment: do you want clicks > 6 && ( lang == 'de' || lang == 'fr' || _id=='506d95bc5c73952c14000002') this way now ?

Comment: yes, but not exactly that. I would like to know how I can dynamically adding more more ORs (I will need to loop though some IDs and add them. It doesn't really have much to do with the question but, if you can help, it'd be appreciated. that new or doesn't have to be inside the brakets

Comment: is it necessary to use OR ? you can use $in operator for list of _id

Comment: oh, you're right!! didn't remember there was $in, aha. Thank you for the answer! it was great help :)

Comment: but, could "$in" be good for this? I need both $in AND the $or results.

Comment: $in gives same result as $or.. good practice to use $in. you can also use $in & $or both at the same time

Comment: well, I seems a bit weird because, if I do:   `$query['$or'] = array(array('lang' => 'de'), array('lang' => 'fr'));
  $query['$in'] = array(array('_id' => new mongoId('506d95bc5c73952c14000002')));` it returns nothing. while if I put the mongoId in the '$or' it does work... strange.

Comment: then way you did i think it is wrong. let me give you example in my answer.

Comment: this still doesn't work. I need to comment out '$or' in order to make it work. basically its like: if I have $in, it will look for that ID only if it's in 'fr' or 'de' the code is the same as yours.

Comment: perhaps it's important to underline that this ID is NOT contained in any of those resulting ORs.

Comment: this way, it works, although that's not very dynamic: `$query['$or'] = array(array('sex' => 'fm'), array('sex' => 'f*'), array('_id' => array('$in' => array(new mongoId('506d95bc5c73952c14000002')))) );`

Answer (score 1):

```
          $cond=array();
          $cond=array_merge($cond,array("clicks" => array('$gt' =>6)));
          $cond=array_merge($cond,array("$or" => array(array("lang" =>'de'),array("lang" =>'fr'))));

    $cursor = $collection->find($cond);

----------------------------

    another way is : 
       $cond=array();
          $cond=array_merge($cond,array("clicks" => array('$gt' =>6)));
          $cond=array_merge($cond,array("$in" => array('de','fr')));

    $cursor = $collection->find($cond);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$or` is good but not extremely index friendly especially when you start getting into more diverse ranges. A slightly more index friendly method is with `$in`:

```
$db->collection->find(array('clicks' => array('$gt' => 6), 
    'lang' => array('$in' => array('fr', 'de'))));
```

That tends to make more efficient use of indexes at times.

Also note that nested `$or`s do not currently use indexes however `$or` can use multiple index plans which means that a query like so:

```
$db->collection->find(array('clicks' => array('$gt' => 6), '$or' => array(
    array('lang' => 'fr'), arrray('lang' => 'de')
))
```

Would be able to use multiple indexes but in this case it is useless since it only going over one field so better to use `$in`.